# How to calculate degree of a node in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

In a undirected graph find the node with the highest sum of the degrees of its neighbors

I dont solve this problem    maybe  use welsh-powell algorithm

Answer (score 0):

```
highest_sum = -1;
best_node = -1
Loop over nodes
  sum = 0;
  Loop over neighbours of the node
     count links connected to neighbour and add to sum
  IF sum > highest_sum
      highest_sum = sum
      best_node = this node
Print best_node
```

Comment: thank you  firstly ,
I'm just learning the subject, could you please explain a little more with pseudo code?

Comment: What coding language are you using?

Comment: only pseudo code-> in an undirected graph
finds the node with the highest sum of the degrees of its neighbors
design an algorithm        I don't want a code in principle, I'm just trying to understand. Thank you for your support.  (and  time complexity is  n^2 ?

Comment: What is it that you do not understand?

Comment: How do we calculate the neighborhood degree?

Comment: Yoe want to know how to calculate the degree of a node?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)